# Powershell: Log my deleted files

Tags: powershell

New to powershell and need some help. My script searches the TEST folder and subfolders, then deletes files older than 21 days. I want to log all the deleted files in a log file.

```
cls 
$Now = Get-Date 
$Days = "21" 
$Targetfolder = "c:\TEST" 
#----- define LastWriteTime parameter based on $Days ---# 
$LastWrite = $Now.AddDays(-$Days) 
#----- get files based on lastwrite filter and specified folder ---# 
$Files = Get-Childitem $TargetFolder -Include $Extension -Exclude *.xml -Recurse | where { $_.LastWriteTime -le "$LastWrite" } 
foreach ($File in $Files) { 
    if ($File -ne $Null) { 
        write-host "Deleting File --> $File" -ForegroundColor "Green" 
        Remove-Item $File.FullName | out-null 
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post your code samples into your question, instead of a comment.  That way it would be easier to track it.

Answer (score 2):

`Add-Content $filename $value`  will do it!

```
cls 
$Now = Get-Date 
$Days = "21" 
$Targetfolder = "c:\TEST" 
$LogFile = "C:\DeletedFiles.txt"
#----- define LastWriteTime parameter based on $Days ---# 
$LastWrite = $Now.AddDays(-$Days) 
#----- get files based on lastwrite filter and specified folder ---# 
$Files = Get-Childitem $TargetFolder -Include $Extension -Exclude *.xml -Recurse | 
        where {$_.LastWriteTime -le "$LastWrite"} 
        foreach ($File in $Files) { 
            if ($File -ne $Null) { 
                Add-Content $LogFile $File.FullName
                write-host "Deleting File --> $File" -ForegroundColor "Green" Remove-Item $File.FullName | out-null 
            } 
        }
```

If you want to make it more robust, you can add a timestamp to the file, so that you know when it was deleted.

```
$myDate = get-date -format -g
$content = $myDate  + "   " + $File.FullName
Add-Content $LogFile $content
```

Comment: @ChrisMichaels, glad to hear.  If this answer solved your problem, please upvote and mark complete.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to write output to log file is by using -Verbose and then use Write-Verbose or 4> after the command

```
Remove-Item $File.FullName -Verbose 4> $log_file_path
```